SwiftUI Widget - Is it possible to open an arbitrary URL when the user taps on a Widget (either via widget URL or AppIntent)
I'm looking to create a widget for a specific use case. I'd like to be able to have a user tap on a button (or the widget itself), and place a phone call. Importantly, the Widget must work while the phone is locked, and not launch the app.
From what I can tell, the only way to place a phone call is to open a URL with the following format:
tel://<phone-number>

The problem is I can't open the URL in a Widget. Here's what I've tried:

I've passed the URL to the .widgetURL method like so

struct BeaconWidgetEntryView : View {
    let entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(entry.name)
                .bold()
            Text(entry.phoneNumber)
                .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
        }
        .widgetURL(URL(string: "tel://\(entry.phoneNumber)")!)
    }
}

This just launches the app, passing in this URL. No good.

I've tried to open the URL in an AppIntent (and perform the action on a button tap), but UIApplication.shared is not available in app extensions.

struct CallContactIntent: AppIntent {
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Call Contact"
    static var authenticationPolicy: IntentAuthenticationPolicy = .alwaysAllowed
    static var openAppWhenRun: Bool = false
    static var isDiscoverable: Bool = false

    @Parameter(title: "Phone Number")
    var phoneNumber: String

    init() { }

    init(phoneNumber: String) {
        self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
    }

    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        guard let callNumber = URL(string: "tel://" + phoneNumber) else { return .result() }

        await UIApplication.shared.open(callNumber) // Not available in extensions

        return .result()
    }
}


I've looked at the openURL environment variable in SwiftUI, but I can't pass that into the AppIntent, since it's not sendable.

struct BeaconWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    @Environment(\.openURL) private var openURL // Not sure what I can do with this...

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(entry.name)
                .bold()
            Text(entry.phoneNumber)
                .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
        }
    }
}

This is closely related to this question, but none of the solutions there work for me.
The reason I haven't yet given up on this is Apple's Widgets are able to do this. I created a Shortcut that calls a phone number, and I'm able to call the number on tap while the phone is locked. Is this another case of Apple giving their own apps access to private APIs?

Any luck here? Trying to accomplish the same.

I’ve confirmed that it’s not possible unfortunately.
